# OnGridReady enzyme test results in "TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatchEvent' of null" for ag-grid React testing

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, ts-jest, react-testing

I am facing an error ***TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatchEvent' of null*** when trying to run an enzyme test to simulate `onGridReady` of an ag-grid table.

**My questions** and places where I am getting stuck...

1. How do I gracefully test the `onGridReady` function properly so that it doesn't error out and I can test that it has been called once ?
2. How do I test the other function `onGridSizeChanged`?
3. The Coverage report says I am missing the line `setTableData` to test - how do I test that line ?

---

This is how myfiles look

**myTable.tsx**

```
imports...

const myTable: React.FC = () => {
  //intialize state variables

  const onGridReady = ({ api }: { api: GridApi }) => {
    setGridApi(api)
    api.sizeColumnsToFit()
    api.setHeaderHeight(10)
  }

  const onGridSizeChanged = () => {
    gridApi?.sizeColumnsToFit()
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (myTableData) {
      if (selectedCountryName !== '') {
        setTableData(objectCopy(myTableData))
      }
    }
  }, [myTableData, selectedCountryName])

  useEffect(() => {
    // do some stuff
  }, [businessDate])

  return <div className={'my-table'}>
    <Grid container spacing={12}>
      <div>
        <h1/>Title</h1>
      </div>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <div data-testid="my-table-grid">
          <AgGridReact
            containerProps={{ style: { height: `${containerHeight}px` } }}
            columnDefs={myTableColumns(moment(fromDate), moment(toDate))}
            onGridReady={onGridReady}
            onGridSizeChanged={onGridSizeChanged}
            onModelUpdated={onGridSizeChanged}
            rowData={tableData}
          />
        </div>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </div >
}

export default myTable
```

**myTable.test.tsx**

```
import myTable from './myTable'
// other imports...

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })

const onGridReady = jest.fn()

function setUpMyTableComponent() {
    const wrapper = shallow(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <myTable >
                <ColumnLayout>
                    <ColumnLayout>
                        <DataGrid onGridReady={onGridReady} />
                    </ColumnLayout>
                </ColumnLayout>
            </myTable >
        </Provider>
    )
    return { wrapper }
}

describe('myTable', () => {

    it('checking myTable', () => {
        const { wrapper } = setUpMyTableComponent()
        expect(wrapper).toBeDefined
        expect(wrapper.find('.my-table')).toBeDefined
    })

    it('simulate onGridReady', async () => {
        const { wrapper } = setUpMyTableComponent()
        const aggrid = wrapper.find(AgGridReact)
        dataGrid.simulate('onGridReady')
        await tick()
        expect(onGridReady).toHaveBeenCalled()
    })

    function tick() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(resolve, 0);
        })
    }

})
```